# SignalR-ObjC in Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, signalr, signalr-hub

i have a problem with SignalR-ObjC in my swift project. I create a connection with SR to my hub, the code is:

```
import UIKit
import SignalR_ObjC


class ViewController: UIViewController, SRConnectionDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var textFied_Username: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textField_Password: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var btn_Login: UIButton!

var hubConnection = SRHubConnection(URLString: "http://myUrl.com");

var hubProxy = SRHubProxy();


var txt_Username : String = "username";
var txt_Password : String = "password";


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func btn_Login(sender: AnyObject) {




    txt_Username = textFied_Username.text!;


    txt_Password = textField_Password.text!;


    hubProxy = SRHubProxy(connection: hubConnection, hubName: "MyHub");

    let signInSelector = Selector("signInResponse:");

    hubProxy.on("signIn", perform: self, selector: signInSelector);


    hubConnection.delegate = self;


    hubConnection.start();

    self.SRConnectionDidOpen(hubConnection);





}

func SRConnectionDidOpen(connection: SRConnectionInterface!) {

    hubProxy.invoke("SignIn", withArgs: ["username","password"])


}


func signInResponse(response: String) {

    NSLog(response);
}

}
```

The connection is established and the invoke works, but it doesn't receive message, the method:

```
hubProxy.on("signIn", perform: self, selector: signInSelector);
```

doesn't work and the selector:

```
signInSelector
```

is never called. Can anyone help me to solve this problem??
Thank you and sorry for my bad english, i hope the question is clear.

Comment: did you solve it!?

Comment: No, finally i used objective c code. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4, Xcode 9**

try to add @objc selector at func declarationm here is my working example:

```
func configureProxy() {
        let proxy: SRHubProxy? = createHubProxy(kHubName) as? SRHubProxy
        // we are using proxy-connection, to avoid parsing NSData ourselves.
        proxy?.on(kReceivedMessageSignalREventName, perform: self, selector: #selector(self.didReceiveMessage(_:)))
    }


@objc func didReceiveMessage(_ message: [AnyHashable: Any]?) {
    if (receiveMessageBlock != nil) {
        receiveMessageBlock!(message)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
hubConnection?.received = { [weak self] received in
        print("Error: \(received)")
    }
```

Comment: What does this code do, how is it different from the original code and why does it solve the problem?